# How can I display "please fill required field" in different languages using jquery.validate and ?lang=?

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using `$lang = $_GET['lang'];` and some arrays to change the language of the page.
So my pages URL look like this when I select a language: `...index.php?lang=en`
(so my index page never changes neither my jquery files)

(more details in my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306763/php-variable-is-activated-when-i-call-it-from-index-file-but-not-from-included-fi))

I'm using jQuery validate plugin to validate my form and a **custom.js**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#sendmail").validate({
        rules: {
            FieldData0: {
                required: true
            },
            FieldData1: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            FieldData2: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            FieldData0: {
                required: "Please enter your name"
            },
            FieldData1: {
                required: "Please enter your email address"
            },
            FieldData2: {
                required: "Please enter a message"
            }
        }
    });
})
```

How can I show different requirement warning for different languages in this case?
Do I have to make a `custom.js` for every language and then use php if else statements, is the a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:  Make a custom-en.js (and one for each language) then have something like the following for in the custom-en.js:

```
var messList = {
     mess1 : "This is message 1";
     ...
     reqMess1 : "Please enter your name";
}
```

then in your non-changing file you would have lines that look like this:

```
    messages: {
        FieldData0: {
            required: messList.reqMess1;
        },
```